# I was thinking about the distribution of numbers primes and I came up with this simple idea. What is this?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Good night.
I was thinking about the distribution of numbers primes and I came up with this simple idea, what do you think?

If we take the number line and wrap it around a circle, the origin of both being the "zero" point, having a radius of $1$, the circumference being all values greater than one of the line, such that:

[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV1vc.png)

Now, if we take the cosine function with period equal to any Natural number, obtaining infinite spirals that wind at different frequencies around the circle.
Something interesting happens if we wind logarithmic functions with the base in any natural; $\log_2 x$, $\log_3x$ ...
Such that:

[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZigU.png)]

Now, my two questions are:
What happens to the prime numbers within these curves; How are the points belonging to each prime number of each of these curves distributed when they are projected on the base circle (it should be noted that the primes go around one on the base circle as well as the curves)?

Imagine an infinity curve such that it never goes around the circle, but contains all the natural numbers. How are all the prime numbers distributed in the circular base? I have the feeling that this second question gives the answer to which number is a prime or not.

Note: Strange things happen when you change the type of curve you roll, but the best thing happens when these are logarithmic

(I speak Spanish an English intermediate, so this text was translated with the help of Google. Sorry for the inconsistencies in it).

Edit after post:
if you visualize this in the complex plane, you will get another curve that I think is the solution to everything this mess, but unfortunately my mathematics does not allow me to express it in any other way than geometric.

Comment: I don't understand your drawings. "each prime number of each of these curves distributed when they are projected on the base circle" ?

Comment: Sí, en realidad las curvas que salen son la visualización de como enrollas los números reales en el círculo; Lo interesante pasa cuando tomas R+ y la enrollas de tal forma que nunca da una vuelta. 

Si prestas atención, no es casualidad que el radio sea 1

Comment: If you want to understand these ideas more, you can visit the following page, which is about the geometric determination of primes: 
http://www.polprimos.com/

Comment: Paying enough attention you will notice that these spirals, when projected onto the circle, form beautiful patterns focusing on the primes. Now I am trying to deduce the Spiral of Sacks from these patterns, and looking for others.
Summing up all this, I believe that there is a curve of this type that determines all the prime numbers around the circle, in such a way that no value of the other curves is on top with this one.

I would put the functions that give rise to this but I have realized that it is easier and more profitable to think in this way.

Comment: Google Translate may not have done a great job of conveying your message, but I think you’ve stumbled upon wheel sieves for identifying prime numbers.

Comment: So this leads nowhere? Any reference to view?
(sorry for Google Translate, I try it but the Hispanic community is not so active)

Comment: @ArturoCarr Welcome to Math SE. Regarding the wheel sieves that Arya mentioned, please check [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, I did it. But I can't find something that represents the same time in complex numbers. Do you know something like that?

Comment: @ArturoCarr I don't know anything like that.

Comment: Well, if this leads nowhere I will proceed to delete it. Thanks